# Transmission stopped working, says it's not installed even though it is

Tags: command-line, transmission

So transmission decided to randomly stop working. When I click on torrents transmission comes up as an option, but when I click ok nothing happens. When I go to the terminal and try to open transmission it tells me it's not installed. it recommends I install it with sudo apt-get install transmission-gtk. When I do this it says something like "transmission already newest version." So it's installed, clearly.

Somebodddy help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gtk transmission client changed name recently from transmission to transmission-gtk. The launcher should be updated accordingly with the new name. However, you might have a custom launcher in your homedir, and this one will not be changed by any package removal/installation.

So, look in `~/.local/share/applications` and move away (or delete) any `.desktop` file with transmission in its name.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like somewhere along the line the environment isn't finding it. *does /usr/bin/transmission-gtk* exist?

If it does not, you will need to purge it as Jan D has outlined.

```
sudo apt-get remove transmission-gtk
```

verify that the package does not exist in your local cache of downloaded packages, and it may be a good time to tidy that up now.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then update your package list and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install transmission-gtk
```

Don't close your terminal so you can copy/paste the log of the installation if it does not correct your issue and update the question with the installation log. It may provide some hints as to whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-common transmission-gtk
```

then,

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-common transmission-gtk
```

This should work.